# Sum of $m$ consecutive square numbers equals $m^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I took a look at some exercises from the IMO. I got stuck at one exercise. The task is the following:

Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that there are $m$ consecutive square numbers, which sum equals $m^3$. And give an example for $m>1$.

As the exercise is adressed to students in their last school year, I assume that there must be some kind of trick or basic calculation to solve this exercise. But I could not find a solution and also didn't want to dive into deeper "university math".

First I tried to assume a finite set and try to find a contradiction. Afterwards I tried to find solutions for 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^m (n+i)^2 = m^3
\end{align*}
with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. But it was not really useful.

I would be thankful for a little advise.

EDIT: Source from the german national wide round (second day) for 12th graders. 1. http://www.mathematik-olympiaden.de/archiv.html
2. http://www.mathematik-olympiaden.de/aufgaben/56/4/A56124b.pdf

Comment: Note that while they don't require university math, the IMO problems are among the hardest last-school-year-level problems one can readily find.

Comment: Do you know a formula for the sum of the first $n$ square numbers? I would try taking the sum of the first $n+m$ squares and deducting the sum of the first $n$ squares which would tell me what the sum of $m$ consecutive squares looks like.

Comment: We can rewrite your formula as 
$$\frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)(2m+2n+1)}{6} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = m^3$$
by using the formula for some of the first $x$ squares

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I tried similar approaches. They led to pretty ugly expressions, which were not really handy for further analysis.

Comment: Which IMO was this problem on?

Comment: Added the source in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As John Lou noted, your sum is equal to

$$\frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)(2m+2n+1)-n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

So, that being equal to $m^3$ is equivalent to

$$(m+n)(m+n+1)(2m+2n+1)-n(n+1)(2n+1) = 6m^3$$

$$2m^3 + 6m^2n + 6mn^2 + 3m^2 + 6mn + m = 6m^3$$

$$6mn+6n^2+3m+6n+1=4m^2.$$

By looking at the form of this, one would like to turn it into a Pell equation. Indeed, it simplifies to

$$(3(m+2n+1))^2-33m^2=3.$$

So, it suffices to show that there exist infinitely many solutions to the Pell equation $x^2-33y^2=3$ where $x\equiv 3y+3\bmod 6$. Since the solutions to a Pell equation are of the form of finitely many recurrence relations, we can get that the solutions in $(x,y)$ are periodic $\bmod$ any integer; specifically, if we can find one solution where $x\equiv 3y+3\bmod 6$, that guarantees that infinitely many exist. Indeed, the solution $m=47,n=21$ guarantees this (I'm not sure of a good way to find this solution, though).

Comment: Thats an interesting way, specially because i didnt hear about Pell's equation before, so learned something new. But I still wonder, if they really await this stuff from 12th graders, feels a bit too advanced.

Comment: @sqlman This is meant to be a fairly difficult problem (problem 6 on the German national olympiad), so it's not that surprising that it uses "difficult" techniques. Also, Pell equations are a fairly standard technique in olympiad math - when I was at an olympiad training program, Pell equations were one of the first things they taught, and one of the things I used the most.(also see the [AoPS forum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1441670p8209257) where they discuss this problem - the solutions seem to be of a similar flavor to this one).